# Kuberentes Update Policy Wait Until Actually Ready

Tags: kubernetes

I have a K8 cluster running with a deployment which has an update policy of RollingUpdate. How do I get Kubernetes to wait an extra amount of seconds or until some condition is met before marking a container as ready after starting?

An example would be having an API server with no downtime when deploying an update. But after the container starts it still needs X amount of seconds before it is ready to start serving HTTP requests. If it marks it as ready immediately once the container starts and the API server isn't actually ready there will be some HTTP requests that will fail for a brief time window.

Comment: did you try adding initialDelaySeconds into this ? If you calculate how much time it takes to intake the http request and accordingly u can set the delay for getting pods ready

Comment: You need a [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/); the pod won't show as "ready" (and the deployment won't proceed) until the probe passes.

Comment: @DavidMaze just been checking it out there, what is the difference between readinessProbe and startupProbe?

Comment: Startup probes are like liveness probes, but only run at startup time; you can configure different check intervals for the startup case.  Also note that startup probes are fairly new (alpha in k8s 1.16, beta in 1.18) and your cluster may not support them.

Comment: Did the suggestion made by David Maze answered your question? If so, please consider adding it as answer- it will be more visible to others who encounter similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Posting @David Maze comment as community wiki for better visibility:

You need a [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes); the pod won't show as "ready" (and the deployment won't proceed) until the probe passes.

Example:

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - /tmp/healthy
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
```

- `initialDelaySeconds`: Number of seconds after the container has
  started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated. Defaults
  to 0 seconds. Minimum value is 0.
- `periodSeconds`: How often (in seconds) to perform the probe. Default
  to 10 seconds. Minimum value is 1.